# catalogsearch_query does have an entry for STRING. How come frontend search on STRING won't bring it up?

Tags: magento-1.8

Magento1.8.Fulltext.

Frontend search does not return `STRING`. `STRING` is in `catalogsearch_query` and in `catalogsearch_fulltext`

Comment: Please share the details of the code.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` WHERE `data_index` LIKE '%STRING%' 
returns 36 entries.
But frontent search returns only 8.
Might be related with :
SELECT * FROM `catalogsearch_query` WHERE `query_text` LIKE '%STRING%'
which returns all rows containing  STRING. One row has the exact STRING match and num-results = 8.

Frontend displays 8 results; not 36. How come ?